# Property 'FacebookAuthProvider' does not exist on type '() => Auth'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use Facebook authentication for my Typescript React app. However, I've run into an error

**Firebase.tsx**

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/firestore"
import "firebase/auth"

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
    "apiKey": "*",
    "authDomain": "*",
    "databaseURL": "*",
    "projectId": "*",
    "storageBucket": "*",
    "messagingSenderId": "*",
    "appId": "*",
    "measurementId": "*"
})

export default app;
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
```

**Facebook.tsx**

```js
import React from "react"
import firebase from "../../../Firebase"
import AnchorButton from "../../AnchorButton/AnchorButton"
import "./Facebook.scss"

export default function Facebook() {

    const onClick = async () => {
        var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()
    }

    return (
        <AnchorButton className="icon facebook" onClick={onClick}>
            <i className="fa fa-facebook"></i>
        </AnchorButton>
    )
}
```

Why does my firebase give me the error:
`Property 'FacebookAuthProvider' does not exist on type '() => Auth'`
This is the same error for `GoogleAuthProvider` and `GithubAuthProvider`.
???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in firebase.tsx

change

```
export default app;
```

to

```
export default firebase;
```

**additional tip**. You may encounter error where app is declared multiple times, so change your firebase.tsx to the following.

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/firestore"
import "firebase/auth"

const firebaseConfig = {
    "apiKey": "*",
    "authDomain": "*",
    "databaseURL": "*",
    "projectId": "*",
    "storageBucket": "*",
    "messagingSenderId": "*",
    "appId": "*",
    "measurementId": "*"
}


//check if app had been initialized
let app;
  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  }

export default firebase;
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me

In my Firebase.tsx:

```
export const facebookProvider = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider
```

In my AuthProvider.tsx:

```
const facebookCredential = facebookProvider.credential(data.accessToken);
```